# Flot: how to use onchange instead of onclick (checkbox) to turn off series?

Tags: flot

I know it's possible to use a legend to turn on/off flot series, as can be seen on [this](http://people.iola.dk/olau/flot/examples/turning-series.html) page.

In that example, the change seems to be the result of the click event.

I'm trying to get this to also work when an `onchange` event is used.

If I (add and then) click this button...

`<input type="button" value="Disable USA" onclick="document.getElementById('idusa').checked = false;">`

...the checkbox is being disabled, but the graph isn't being redrawn.

I tried to fix this issue in two ways:

1. I added `plotAccordingToChoices();` to the `onclick` of the button, and
2. I changed the `choiceContainer.find("input").click(plotAccordingToChoices);` code: tried using `change` instead of `click`.

This didn't work. Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

This is a really tough problem, as far as I know (and I don't know that much) changing the checkbox from the button will not fire its change event, but since you're using a function, you can just change the attribute, then fire the redraw function. I also changed the .click() to .change() just for effect:

From Flot code, I added a class to each element and set that class to have a change event:

```
choiceContainer.append('<br/><input type="checkbox" name="'
 + key+'" checked="checked" id="id' + key + '" class="legend">' +
 '<label for="id' + key + '">' + val.label + '</label>');
$(".legend").change(plotAccordingToChoices);
```

Now for your button, I made it toggle USA:

```
    $("#clicker").click( function(){
    if($("#idusa").is(":checked"))
        $("#idusa").attr('checked', false);
    else
        $("#idusa").attr('checked',true)
    plotAccordingToChoices();
    });
```

**EDIT:**
You can use .trigger('change') to fire the change event.

```
    $("#clicker").click( function(){
    if($("#idusa").is(":checked"))
        $("#idusa").attr('checked', false);
    else
        $("#idusa").attr('checked',true)
    $("#idusa").trigger('change');
    });
```

Finally I changed the button to a button:

```
<button id="clicker">Disable USA</button>
```

You could modify this a little and have a button for each checkbox if you wanted.
I hope this works for you.